# PHP-API with TCPDF and direct download of PDF with Angular-Client

Tags: php, angular, download

I´m trying download a tcpdf direcctly from php-api with an angular client, but I always get too small and damaged pdf. When I save the pdf with option "F" the file is Ok, so I assume that there is something wrong, when transporting it to the client.

API-side Model

```
[...]
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, true, true, true, '');
return $pdf->Output('temp.pdf', 'S');
```

API-side Controller

```
[...]
$response->getBody()->write((string)$events);
$response = $response->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
return $response;
```

Client-side Service

```
getMonthlyPdf(viewStart: Date, viewEnd: Date): Observable<string> {
    return this.http.post<string>(`${environment.serviceHost}/events/monthlyPdf`, { start: viewStart, end: viewEnd }, httpOptions);
  }
```

Client-side Controller

```
async generateMonthly(): Promise<void> {
    const file = await firstValueFrom(this.eventService.getMonthlyPdf(this.starttimeOfMonth, this.endtimeOfMonth));
    var blob = new Blob([file], { type: 'application/pdf' });
    var downloadURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = downloadURL;
    link.download = "help.pdf";
    link.click();
  }
```

Comment: Don't use AJAX for a file download. Just submit an invisible form.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved it now:

API-side Model:

```
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, true, true, true, '');
return $pdf->Output('temp.pdf', 'I'); // changed from S to I
```

API-side Controller:

```
$response->getBody()->write((string)$pdf);
$response = $response->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf'); // changed from Octet-Stream to PDF
return $response;
```

CLient-Service:

```
getMonthlyPdf(viewStart: Date, viewEnd: Date): Observable<Blob> {
    return this.http.post<Blob>(`${environment.serviceHost}/events/monthlyPdf`, { start: viewStart, end: viewEnd }, { headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}), responseType : 'blob' as 'json'});
  } // added responseType 'blob' as 'json'
```

CLient-Controller:

```
generateMonthly(): void {
    this.eventService.getMonthlyPdf(this.starttimeOfMonth, this.endtimeOfMonth).pipe(take(1))
    .subscribe((response) => {
        const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
        downloadLink.href = URL.createObjectURL(response);

        downloadLink.download = 'Monatsprogramm_' + formatDate(this.starttimeOfMonth, 'MMMM_y', 'de-DE') + '.pdf';
        downloadLink.click();
    });
  }
```